# CMake: Own Shared libray in Windows: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, shared

I have a **CMake project with the next structure**:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── app
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
│
└── theLib
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── internal
    │   ├── internal.cpp
    │   └── internal.h
    ├── myprint.cpp
    └── myprint.h
```

And **the output tree** is:

```
├── app
│   └── app.exe
├── theLib
│   └── libtheLib.dll
```

If I compile the program **under linux, all works perfect**, but when I do it **under Windows, compile fine, but app.exe doesn't execute;**
I get the next error:

```
*app.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libtheLib.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.*
```

**I suspect that don't links the internal.cpp, because, when I move its procedures to inline into internal.h, then works fine.**

Any help please?

Here are the files:
**root::CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME "testProject")
project(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

#set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(BIN_PATH "binAPP")
set(TMP_BUILD "tmpBuild")
set(LIB_PATH "theLib")
set(APP_PATH "app")

set(OUT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../${BIN_PATH})
set(BUILD_TEMP_PATH ${OUT_PATH}/${TMP_BUILD})

add_subdirectory(${LIB_PATH} ${BUILD_TEMP_PATH}/${LIB_PATH})
include_directories(${LIB_PATH})

add_subdirectory(${APP_PATH} "${BUILD_TEMP_PATH}/${APP_PATH}")
include_directories(${APP_PATH})
```

**app::CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUT_PATH}/${APP_PATH}) #/${APP_PATH}

include_directories(        

)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(${APP_PATH} ${SOURCES})
add_dependencies(${APP_PATH} ${LIB_PATH})   
target_link_libraries(${APP_PATH} PUBLIC ${LIB_PATH} )
```

**theLib::CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUT_PATH}/${LIB_PATH}) 
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUT_PATH}/${LIB_PATH})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUT_PATH}/${LIB_PATH})

include_directories(        
    #./internal
)

add_library(${LIB_PATH}             SHARED 
            myprint.h
            myprint.cpp
            ./internal/internal.h
            ./internal/internal.cpp
)
set(LINK_DIRS
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"  
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/internal"
)
target_include_directories(${LIB_PATH} PUBLIC ${LINK_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries(${LIB_PATH} PUBLIC )
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Are the exe and the dll in the same output folder?

Comment: Thank you. No, If they're, then executes, but I try to have them in separated folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the application can find your dll. To do this you have to:

1. Put the exe and the dlll into the same folder
2. Add the folder where the dll can be found to your PATH-environment variable.

Here you can learn more about the dll-loading [How dll get loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: Thank you, Preferably I don't want to use the PATH enviroment variable. Is it possible under windows? There is no problem under Linux

Comment: Ok, I just read that is not possible under windows, then could I use cmake to modify the windows path variable??.. I asume yes, I will try, thank you very much